Ifelse using rownames in r is treating row numbers not as integers
I have a block of code that look like this:
ParticipantNum <- c(1,2,4,5,7,8,9,10,13,15,16,17,18,22,24,26,27,28,29,30,32,33,35,36,39,41,43,44,45,49,50,53,54)
ParticipantTime <- c(55,54,56,88,54,79,64,52,48,21,54,87,62,35,54,87,96,96,87,53,54,52,32,89,11,28,47,78,22,14,49,75,45)
summary <- data.frame(Number=ParticipantNum,Time=ParticipantTime,Category='')
summary$Category <- ifelse(row.names(summary)<=3,"Dogs","Cats")

I am setting up a dataframe with 3 columns: Number, Time, and Category, where category is Dogs and Cats. I want my dataframe to make rows 1-3 say Dogs and all other rows say Cats. (This is an example for clarity). Somehow, when I do this, it makes rows 1-3 say Dogs, as well as rows 10-29. Rows 4-9 and 30-33 (the last row) say Cats. My intuition says it's treating row 10-29 as being "less than 3" because the first character of the row name is less than 3. I don't know why it would be doing this. I've read through the documentation for rownames and row.names but I don't understand it well enough to fix my problem. I'm new to r and relatively new to coding. Thanks.
enter image description here

See Why does adding attributes to a dataframe take longer with large dataframes?

The issue is with how row.names works. If you look at the documentation, it is subtle but says:

Row names of the form 1:n for n > 2 are stored internally in a compact form, which might be seen from C code or by deparsing but never via row.names or attr(x, "row.names").

And for numeric operations:

row.names will always return a character vector. (Use attr(x, "row.names") if you need to retrieve an integer-valued set of row names.)

So your code will work if you use attr(summary, "row.names"), but using as.numeric is probably nicer looking.
ParticipantNum <- c(1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 22, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 32, 33, 35, 36, 39, 41, 43, 44, 45, 49, 50, 53, 54)
ParticipantTime <- c(55, 54, 56, 88, 54, 79, 64, 52, 48, 21, 54, 87, 62, 35, 54, 87, 96, 96, 87, 53, 54, 52, 32, 89, 11, 28, 47, 78, 22, 14, 49, 75, 45)
summary <- data.frame(Number = ParticipantNum, Time = ParticipantTime, Category = "")
# summary$Category <- ifelse(attr(summary, "row.names") <= 3, "Dogs", "Cats")
summary$Category <- ifelse(as.numeric(row.names(summary)) <= 3, "Dogs", "Cats")
summary
#>    Number Time Category
#> 1       1   55     Dogs
#> 2       2   54     Dogs
#> 3       4   56     Dogs
#> 4       5   88     Cats
#> 5       7   54     Cats
#> 6       8   79     Cats
#> 7       9   64     Cats
#> 8      10   52     Cats
#> 9      13   48     Cats
#> 10     15   21     Cats
#> 11     16   54     Cats
#> 12     17   87     Cats
#> 13     18   62     Cats
#> 14     22   35     Cats
#> 15     24   54     Cats
#> 16     26   87     Cats
#> 17     27   96     Cats
#> 18     28   96     Cats
#> 19     29   87     Cats
#> 20     30   53     Cats
#> 21     32   54     Cats
#> 22     33   52     Cats
#> 23     35   32     Cats
#> 24     36   89     Cats
#> 25     39   11     Cats
#> 26     41   28     Cats
#> 27     43   47     Cats
#> 28     44   78     Cats
#> 29     45   22     Cats
#> 30     49   14     Cats
#> 31     50   49     Cats
#> 32     53   75     Cats
#> 33     54   45     Cats

Created on 2024-11-04 with reprex v2.1.1.9000

Notice that your data as given
df0 = data.frame(Number = c(1,2,4,5,7,8,9,10,13,15,16,17,18,22,24,26,27,28,29,30,32,33,35,36,39,41,43,44,45,49,50,53,54), Time = c(55,54,56,88,54,79,64,52,48,21,54,87,62,35,54,87,96,96,87,53,54,52,32,89,11,28,47,78,22,14,49,75,45), Category = "Cats")

does not depend on row names.
Simply do
df0$Category[seq(nrow(df0)) <= 3] = "Dogs"

giving
> head(df0)
  Number Time Category
1      1   55     Dogs
2      2   54     Dogs
3      4   56     Dogs
4      5   88     Cats
5      7   54     Cats
6      8   79     Cats


We moved the vectors inside data.frame(), replaced <- with =, use "Cats" as default Category and avoid ifelse().
